# Is cyclohexane‐1,3‐dicarboxylic acid a correct IUPAC name?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds, cyclohexane

I did the numbering by taking all the functional groups in principal chain (scheme **A**), but my teacher did it differently and proposed the name **cyclohexane‐1,3‐dicarboxylic acid** (scheme **B**):

[image: numbering schemes for cyclohexane‐1,3‐dicarboxylic acid]

The principal chain in my teacher's answer is shorter. Also, he did not put any $\ce{-COOH}$ in the principal chain which he could have done.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The principal "chain" is the ring of six atoms.

Comment: The truth is naming organic compounds is screwy. There is a massive set of rules for naming which is still growing as inventive organic chemists synthesize weirder and weirder compounds. So it takes practice to learn to name properly.

Comment: There are two problems with your attempt at naming. First the carboxylate is a functional group. So it might or might not be part of the primary carbon chain. Second if the carboxylate group had been a methyl group then the molecule would be 1,3-dimethylcyclohexane (which doesn't completely specify the particular isomer). So there is no one word name for that particular carbon structure, eg toluene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question is actually pretty interesting, I think.  @user55119 's comment that the principal chain is the cyclohexane ring is correct -- but it seems like you understand that that's what the teacher is saying, and you're asking, "why?"  The best short answer, too, is imho in your comments: @MaxW 's "naming organic compounds is just screwy" is the bottom-line answer, because there are so many crazy special cases to deal with that it sometimes seems like sorcery to come up with them.  But if one is willing to dig into it a little, 99% of them do actually have consistent reasoning behind them -- even if coming up with that reasoning can feel pretty byzantine right up to the point where you get it.  This can be particularly true for cyclic compounds, which can in some cases even have more than one valid IUPAC name.

In this particular case, the reason your answer is incorrect is because what you defined with your numbering isn't a chain.

Per IUPAC, a chain is a sequence of linked units that is bounded by precisely two "boundary units" -- either a branch point or an "end unit", which is itself defined by IUPAC as a unit* of the macromolecule that is bound to only one other unit.

Now, this clearly causes problems with cyclic compounds, so the IUPAC has some caveats included within the definition of a chain -- one being that a cyclic macromolecule with no end groups is *also* a chain.  So, a chain is either linear and has two boundary groups terminating it, or it's strictly cyclical and includes no end units.  That means a cycloalkane -- including the cyclohexane in your example -- is a valid chain.

Your numbering, however, contains *one* boundary group.  The unit at position 1 is a valid boundary group, as it is connected to only one other group.  The unit at position 7, however, is *not* a boundary group; it is connected to a total of two other units (#6 and #2), and worse, it's a non-boundary that you can't continue counting from either since you've already counted the other molecule it attaches to!

"Maybe it solves the problem if I start from the unit I called #3, and leave the hanging methyl group to be the last part of the chain instead of starting from it -- so the chain would start at current #3 and end at current #1, 3-4-5-6-7-2-1."  (You may want to be looking at your illustration while you read this; it'll probably make the counting I am referring to clearer than just imagining it.)  No, that also doesn't work; it obviously that just puts the problem at the other end -- it still has only one boundary unit, because while the unit at the end of that new "chain" attempt, #1, is only connected to one other, the first unit in the "chain" (#3) is connected to two units, not one, so is not a boundary unit.  Still stuck!

And of course, you can try counting from your #2 instead of your #1 or #3, but then you go all the way around and never have a way to include that methyl group hanging off of #2 -- you'd have to "step" onto #2 again, effectively counting it twice, to then "step" onto the tail CH.  (I wish I could make a video of this "pointing" at each unit in the count; it would come out much clearer, I think!)

So in effect, really the *only* way you have to count the components of the macromolecule and get a coherent chain out of it is to start on #2 and end on the connection between #7 and #2 -- meaning you end up with the most practical solution being exactly the caveat that IUPAC settled on in specifying that a cyclic alkene can itself also be counted as a chain.

From there, I imagine you can figure out the rest: the cyclohexane as a valid chain is also the longest chain,  you start numbering from the functional group, etc.  Hope that helped explain the teacher's answer!

---

---

**Edit/addendum**: Some in the comment have asked for authoritative sourcing of the above.  Good point, and thank you for bringing to my attention that I only stated what I used for sourcing but neither completely cited nor offered links to said sourcing.  First post here in the chemistry StackExchange; please forgive my error.

IUPAC's authoritative reference work for nomenclature is their so-called Gold Book -- the Compendium of Chemical Terminology.

> *IUPAC. Compendium of Chemical Terminology, 2nd ed. (the "Gold Book"). Compiled by A. D. McNaught and A. Wilkinson. Blackwell Scientific
> Publications, Oxford (1997). Online version (2019-) created by S. J.
> Chalk. ISBN 0-9678550-9-8. https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.*

I cite various definitions from within the Gold Book, the following two being of particular importance:
IUPAC - chain (Note 2). https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C00946
IUPAC - end-group. https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/E02092

To address one of the comments in particular: it should be noted that nowhere in the Gold Book is there an authoritative definition of the term "ring."  That would make claim that "according to IUPAC a ring cannot be a chain," already dubious based on the definition I cited above, even less likely to be the case -- they certainly aren't going to "prohibit" something they don't even define.

The complaint about the definition of "chain" referring to "polymers" as if it were a notation of exclusivity and implying that the Gold Book's definition somehow contradicts or does not apply to the Blue Book should be pretty handily refuted with a bit more reading in both the Blue and Gold books. The Blue Book states it doesn't deal with *preferred* naming of polymers, but does still define the systematic naming of organic structures whether polymeric or not.  (Blue Book P-11, p.3)  The Gold Book defines "polymer," very simply and with no caveats, as "a substance composed of macromolecules."  Since "chain" and "polymer" thus both use the term "macromolecules," one would naturally be led to read that definition as well, where along with the (hopefully) uncontroversial definition of being a high-molecular mass chain of repeated low-molecular mass components, one might stumble onto Note 2:

> "If a part or the whole of the molecule has a high relative molecular mass and essentially comprises the multiple repetition of units derived, actually or conceptually, from molecules of low relative molecular mass, it may be described as either macromolecular or polymeric, or by polymer used adjectivally."

No clearer acknowledgement of the lack of some "hard line" apparently perceived by some between polymers and "regular" organic macromolecules should be necessary.

When it comes to systematic naming, especially, polymers aren't a "special class" of substance which are somehow privy to different definitions and procedures -- indeed, the Blue Book tells us that's precisely the opposite of the case.  So, for those strictly systematic purposes (which is the entire point of the question, and should be in most introductory academic settings because the point isn't to have students memorize some esoteric rules but instead to teach them something about the *structure* of molecules and their function within a larger compound) - the definition of "chain" given applies just fine. In fact, the definition of "polymer" is expressly defined in the Gold Book, again IUPAC's authoritative text, such that it could apply to any simple alkane with a side branch for the purposes of that text.  Rather than second-guess clearly written prose, I'd rather assume the working group knew what it was doing there by leaving it vague and allowing common usage to define terms that are inherently ambiguous.  (Also see: [What is the difference between Alkanes and Polymers?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48159/what-is-the-difference-between-alkanes-and-polymers))  They seem more aware that strict legalism doesn't serve their purposes than most of the practitioners of their work do.

And for those of you who skipped this addendum entirely: good for you.  As interesting as some of the contentions below are, it seems generally agreed by all that none actually change the correct answer to the original question asked anyway; whatever your take on the semantic issues around the Blue and Gold (and Purple!) books that took up half the comments, they're just that -- semantics.  One can think that an answer is based on a definition that is "irrelevant" due to its source, which I find an odd and not particularly useful criticism (but hey, that's just me); but thinking then that said definition is "incorrect" is false logic.  If someone who has never seen a math book in their life believes 2+2=4 because some hot dog vendor on a street corner told them so, it doesn't make 2+2 equal anything other than 4.  Fortunately for them, just because their source has "no relevance" doesn't mean that they can't have a grasp of basic math.

Comment: (to explain the asterisk in the "end unit" definition)
*  IUPAC states that a "feature group" that provides a macromolecule its name, like a carboxyl group in a carboxylic acid, can count as an end unit as well.  Figured somebody might mention that, if I didn't. :) Doesn't directly impact the core problem, though.

Comment: I am missing authoritative sources for most of these claims; and a couple of ones I find misleading. For what it's worth, I think in the latest edition the terminology of 'principal chain' is superseded by 'parent compound'. It's not crazy sorcery to name the compounds, there are just many rules to follow and it might not be easy to know them all. But that is just studying and has little to nothing to do with the chemistry that is behind it. I don't agree with "[…] which can in some cases even have more than one valid IUPAC name." There is always exactly one preferred name.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/93534/4945

Comment: "IUPAC has some caveats included within the definition of a chain -- one being that a cyclic macromolecule with no end groups is also a chain" No. According to IUPAC nomenclature, the parent structure can be a ring or a chain, but a ring cannot be a chain.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン,   thank you for noting my lack of specific sourcing. As I said in the original post, the sourcing was IUPAC; I have edited the post by adding an endcap to specifically cite the Gold Book and the entries within that were applicable.  

To answer your two specific issues w/the answer: I did not say it was "crazy sorcery" to name compounds; in fact, we largely agree:  

"...it sometimes **_seems_** like sorcery to come up with them. **But** if one is willing to dig into it a little, **99% of them do actually have consistent reasoning behind them**..." (emphasis added)  

1/2

Comment: And IUPAC agrees wrt possible naming ambiguity (ref. earlier citation, "chain", _Gold Book_): "_Note 1: Except in linear single-strand macromolecules, the definition of a chain may be somewhat arbitrary._" * Your second issue: "_I don't agree with "[…] which can in some cases even have more than one valid IUPAC name." There is always exactly one preferred name._" Those two statements do not contradict. There is one preferred name, agreed. There can still be multiple valid names. I am reminded (due to the comment below yours) of benzene, or cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene. One preferred, both valid. 2/2

Comment: @Martin-マーチンone final note: you cite https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/93534/4945 in defense of your comment re: preferred and valid names. The accepted answer in that very same post begins by stating precisely my point: "_The problem with systematic IUPAC names is that many compounds can have **more than one** systematic IUPAC name. A compound may be named **correctly** in two or more ways in accordance with the several methods recommended by IUPAC._" (emphasis added)
I hope that puts that issue to bed.  Thank you again for your attention to improve this answer.

Comment: @Loong _"IUPAC has some caveats included within the definition of a chain -- one being that a cyclic macromolecule with no end groups is also a chain" No. According to IUPAC nomenclature, the parent structure can be a ring or a chain, but a ring cannot be a chain._  I'm sorry, but the IUPAC definition, which I referenced and now explicitly cite in the answer, says quite the opposite.  IUPAC _Gold Book_, "chain" https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C00946, Note 2: "A cyclic macromolecule has no end groups but may nevertheless be regarded as a chain."

Comment: Perhaps you were meaning that a ring (or cyclic structure in general) can't be a *component* of a chain?  That still would unfortunately require some caveats, but on the whole it would certainly at least apply to the OP's issue, since their error could be described as misnumbering the "chain" as starting behind the methyl branch, which effectively results in  calling the branch and the ring two "components" of the same "chain" which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @George "A cyclic macromolecule has no end groups but may nevertheless be regarded as a chain." – You quote the _Glossary of basic terms in polymer science_ (IUPAC Recommendations 1996), which is not applicable here since it applies to the polymer chain of a macromolecule. You should have looked into _Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013_ instead.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. The Gold Book entry explicitly says "chain (in polymers)". The given compound is not a polymer, and even if it were, the cited definition does not help in choosing a preferred IUPAC name. In this context the "chain" that user55119 mentioned refers to something entirely different, namely the "parent structure" as described in P-12 of the IUPAC Blue Book. I don't mean to be unkind, but I do mean to be blunt, since this "discussion" has gone on so long already: you have based your answer on a definition that is irrelevant, which unfortunately makes it incorrect.

Comment: @Loong Sorry, you are incorrect.  I did not quote the "Glossary of basic terms in polymer science."  As I said, I quoted the Gold Book: https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C00946  In that link, the proper way to cite the definition I gave is clearly specified by the Gold Book itself:  
---
**Cite as:** _IUPAC. Compendium of Chemical Terminology, 2nd ed. (the "Gold Book"). Compiled by A. D. McNaught and A. Wilkinson. Blackwell Scientific Publications, Oxford (1997). Online version (2019-) created by S. J. Chalk. ISBN 0-9678550-9-8. https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook._ 1/2

Comment: Perhaps you did a generic academic search for the text I provided?  Because yes, you would've certainly seen a hit for the 1996 publication that you mention, published by IUPAC's Commission on Macromolecular Nomenclature.  The Gold Book made that the canonical definition by incorporating it, probably with some minor edits as the Gold Book editors specify in its preface text that they tend to do.  (As I'm sure you know, the Blue Book "Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry" is rather light on glossary-style definitions.) 2/2

Comment: @orthocresol the definition applies -- your assertion that the Blue Book's "parent structure" is what is being referred to is itself actually incorrect.  As most of the Blue Book is primarily concerned with preferred nomenclature, they describe a "parent structure" simply as a structure for which they will select a preferred name.  (P-12.1 Preferred IUPAC Names, p.3 Blue Book (2013): "It is necessary to select a preferred alternative in many instances in the construction of the names of organic compounds. Preferred IUPAC names are given to parent structures") 1/2

Comment: They later go on to more strictly define "parent structure" (in bold), and they give examples in that definition -- one of which is quinoline.  That is what demonstrates your error: quinoline, while having one "simple" preferred IUPAC name, is actually *two* linked structures, as its systematic name reveals: 1-benzopyridine.
So, you as with others prior are also conflating conversations on preferred vs systematic IUPAC naming, and missing the point of the question and the answer given -- teaching a student what the systematic naming explains about the structure of the compound itself. 2/2

Comment: (as for the Gold Book's use of the "in polymers" tag, I go into that a bit in the latest edit to the answer.)

Comment: So your claim is that, while the Blue Book assigns a preferred name, you can use polymer terminology from the Gold Book to assign a systematic name to a molecule that is decidedly neither a polymer nor macromolecule?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question doesn't make any sense.  The Blue Book is clear that the assigning of a preferred name doesn't invalidate any of the (possibly multiple) valid systematic names of a compound.  And the Gold Book doesn't have any method of "assigning a systematic name" at all.  It is a glossary, a compendium of definitions.  Perhaps you could restate your question?

Comment: Why do you think the Gold Book definition of chain is at all relevant to a molecule that is neither a polymer nor a macromolecule?

Comment: Looking at your edit: you claim that there isn't a clear line, but there is at least *some* kind of line: which part of cyclohexane-1,3-dicarboxylic acid satisfies this definition *"If a part or the whole of the molecule has a high relative molecular mass and essentially comprises the multiple repetition of units derived, actually or conceptually, from molecules of low relative molecular mass"*? Answer: it doesn't. It's not a macromolecule or a polymer.

Comment: The system tells me this discussion should be moved to chat.  But since you asked a question -- methyl groups are low relative molecular mass, and repetitions of the said group make up any and every alkane, including cyclohexane.  For the purposes of systematic nomenclature that's all you need.  The original poster doesn't need to understand the difference between polyethylene and any other alkene chain to correctly systematically name either.

Comment: Also to that point, and particularly to the arbitrary distinction btw polymers and "just another chain" (especially when it comes to systematic naming): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48159/what-is-the-difference-between-alkanes-and-polymers

I'd be happy to continue discussing this with you over chat.  This has gone widely off relevance from the original question.

Comment: That is OK, as I have no intention of continuing this discussion. I understand now where the disagreement lies. It is not about systematic or preferred naming (I never brought that up, so you saying that I conflated it with something else is slightly ironic), nor is it about the provenance of your Gold Book citation (note that there's no need to perform a generic search for the text, as the Gold Book tells you where the definition is taken from). The issue is just that you think this thing can be called, or considered, a polymer.

Comment: Of course there's not -- which is why I found it odd to be told I quoted something other than the Gold Book.  And the issue isn't my thinking it's a polymer; it's a combination of two heterogenous "chains," certainly not a polymer.  What I said was that the definition of "chain" in the Gold Book is perfectly applicable to the student's issue here, and is not incorrect in said context -- and that neither the Gold nor Blue books give any reason to think it would be incorrect in said context.  So, really, the disagreement lies in whether or not we should be answering the question that was asked.